# pyspark join rdds by a specific key

Tags: join, pyspark, rdd

I have two rdds that I need to join them together. They look like the followings:

RDD1

```
[(u'2', u'100', 2),
 (u'1', u'300', 1),
 (u'1', u'200', 1)]
```

RDD2

```
[(u'1', u'2'), (u'1', u'3')]
```

My desired output is:

```
[(u'1', u'2', u'100', 2)]
```

So I would like to select those from RDD2 that have the same second value of RDD1. I have tried join and also cartesian and none is working and not getting even close to what I am looking for. I am new to Spark and would appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks

Comment: Do you allow to use Spark Dataframe for this solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me your process looks like manual. Here is sample code:-

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(u'2', u'100', 2),(u'1', u'300', 1),(u'1', u'200', 1)])
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(u'1', u'2'), (u'1', u'3')])
newRdd = rdd1.map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])).join(rdd.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1],x[2]))))
newRdd.map(lambda x:(x[1][0], x[0], x[1][1][0], x[1][1][1])).coalesce(1).collect()
```

OUTPUT:-

```
[(u'1', u'2', u'100', 2)]
```

Comment: I am having limited knowledge on RDDs. could you please more elaborate on the last map function. newRdd.map(lambda x:(x[1][0], x[0], x[1][1][0], x[1][1][1])). Thanks

Comment: @vikrantrana I used second map to output in the desired format `[(u'1', u'2', u'100', 2)]` else without second map out would be `[('2', ('1', ('100', 2)))]`

Answer (score 7):

**Dataframe** If you allow using Spark Dataframe in the solution. You can turn given RDD to dataframes and join the corresponding column together.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema=['d', 'a'])
rdd_join = df1.join(df2, on='a')
out = rdd_join.rdd.collect()
```

**RDD** just zip the key that you want to join to the first element and simply use `join` to do the joining

```
rdd1_zip = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[2])))
rdd2_zip = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
rdd_join = rdd1_zip.join(rdd2_zip)
rdd_out = rdd_join.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0][0], x[1][0][1], x[1][1])).collect() # flatten the rdd
print(rdd_out)
```

Comment: This looks cool as well but I wanted a solution using rdds operations rather than dataframes.

Comment: @dagg3r definitely, I'll update an answer if I can solve that using RDD!