# Match keys and join 2 RDD's in pyspark without using dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, rdd

I have 2 RDD's.

```
RDD 1:
[['1', 'user1', 'Name1'],
 ['2', 'user4', 'Name2']]

RDD 2:
[['5', '1a', '3', '99', 'g1'],
 ['11', '2b', '1', '99', 'g2'],
 ['12', '3c', '2', '99', 'g3']]
```

I have to join the above 2 RDD's using the first field in RDD 1 (1,2) etc with the 3rd field in RDD2 (3,1,2) etc and get matching rows written to new output RDD only if its available in both. I know there is a join operation that can be performed. but not sure how.

```
Required output
[['1','Name1'],
 ['2','Name2']]
```

How to proceed with this? Is there a way to do this without using dataframes?

The answers in a similar question did not help me find an ideal solution. So i had to post the query again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark join rdds by a specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821955/pyspark-join-rdds-by-a-specific-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also join RDDs. This code will give you exactly what you want.

```
tuple_rdd1 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x(0), x(2)))
tuple_rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x(2), 0)) )
result = tuple_rdd1.join(tuple_rdd2).map(lambda x:  [x[0], x[1][0] ])
```

The 1st line selects the key and the name in rdd1. Line 2 selects the 3rd column of rdd2 and the last line joins the two and puts the result in the desired format.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the issue. The key is 0 in tuple_rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x(2), 0)) ). I was getting a index out of range issue and this solution solved it.